# VS2013 fails with variadic template specialization

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, variadic-templates

This piece of code works fine with g++ and Clang:

```
template <typename Sig, Sig& S> struct OpF;

template <typename TR, typename ... Ts, TR (&f)(Ts...)>
struct OpF<TR (Ts...), f> {
};

int foo(int x) {
  return 0;
}

OpF<int (int), foo> f;
```

But the new shiny VS2013 compiler bails out with

```
f.cpp(4) : error C3520: 'Ts' : parameter pack must be expanded in this context
```

Which one is at fault?

Comment: Report it as a bug, while there's still a chance they'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I have no MS account and I won't give my personal data to them, so no bug report from me.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the VS2013 compiler, which seems to have been fixed now. For a workaround, see: [Visual C++ 12 (VS2013 Preview) variadic template with function parameter workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399976/visual-c-12-vs2013-preview-variadic-template-with-function-parameter-workaro?lq=1). However, your code probably still won't compile, due to another bug in the VS2013 compiler, which causes it to parse the template argument `TR (&f)(Ts...)` as `TR (&f)(void)`.  Though, there is a workaround for that too. You can use a nested class, which then can use the parameter pack. For example:

```
template <typename Sig> struct OpF;

template <typename TR, typename ... Ts>
struct OpF<TR (Ts...)> {
  template <TR (&f)(Ts...)>
  struct Fn {
  };
};

int foo(int x) {
  return 0;
}

OpF<int (int)>::Fn<foo> f;
```

Template parameters after a parameter pack are not allowed in template *declarations*. However, Clang and GCC do allow it in a template *specialization*. So it could be that Clang and GCC are being too liberal with the C++11 specs.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a bug (in VC++) there is a spare template parameter after the variadic list. This is not valid C++ 11.

Looks like a bug in GCC and CLang.

Comment: Original code looks valid to me.  The second declaration is a partial specialization of the first, and `OpF<int(int), foo>` matches that specialization: `TR=int`, `Ts...={int}`, `f=::foo`.

Comment: @aschepler
Sorry, failed to format that correctly within 5 minutes, should have read...

I disagree, the standard (or at least the Jan 2012 working draft) lists the following example as invalid:
`template<class... T, T... Values> struct static_array;  
    // error: Values expands template type parameter  
    // pack T within the same template parameter list  `  
Effectively this is what is going on within the specialization. I think, (but am not entirely sure, hopefully that can be answered) that a template specialization must itself be a valid template.

Comment: PS. Still couldn't get line breaks formatted correctly, sorry.